# Xampp Config Files AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, xampp, bitnami

I've setup my Bitnami AMI on AWS. I now want to know if there is a way I can change my Xammp config files to access apache and MySQL on the AWS server.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,
XAMPP includes MySQL and Apache.

If you want to connect a remote MySQL, you need to follow this guide:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/MySQL#How_to_connect_to_the_MySQL_database_from_a_different_machine.3f

But in your case, I think you want to migrate you XAMPP site to your AMI.
This guide could help you with that purpose:
https://www.apachefriends.org/docs/hosting-xampp-on-aws.html

I hope it helps.